# RegionIntersection and ListSurfacePlot3D

Tags: graphics3d, regions

I have a 3D surface and I am trying to find the intersection of this and some line. I have a list of list of three dimensional points (I don't know if the way these are generated is important but we take some random points on the disk, apply some map to these and that is the resulting list) and I am using `ListSurfacePlot3D` to plot the surface. `RegionIntersection` says the output of the `ListSurfacePlot3D` is not a correctly specified region. I am not very experienced with the Graphics packages in Mathematica so I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: you need to add your code if you are seeking elaborate help.

Comment: Try `DiscretizeGraphics[ListSurfacePlot[...]]` to get a mesh region from it which is suitable for RegionIntersection.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's definitely closer to what I need but I get errors "Skeleton is not a graphics directive." and "Coordinate Skeleton[3008] should be a triple of numbers, or a Scaled form." and the same with "Skeleton[951]. I'm not sure if this is just an error because of the choice of points or something that is fixable. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You should post your code, but if you're getting errors like that, it probably means your list of points to plot contains a [`Skeleton`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Skeleton.html) form or `<<...>>`. The data is likely bad.